# How to get a random number between min and max? Min and max also random

Tags: c#

When you press the button it generates two random numbers for min and max. I need to put the numbers in a list and pick a random number to display in a label. The if statement will not print the error message, it gives me the error"Input string was not put in correct format". Also I've tried to put the random numbers in a list and I just can not get it figured out.Tips or advice would be appreciated a lot. Thank you

```
    private void GoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int min = r.Next();
        int max = r.Next();

        MinLabel.Text = min.ToString();
        MaxLabel.Text = max.ToString();
        RandomValueLabel.Text = (MinOrMax(min, max)).ToString();
        Between(min, max);
        ListValueLabel.Text = Between(min, max).ToString();

    }

    private int MinOrMax(int min, int max)
    {
        if (min > max)
        {
            string message;
            message = Convert.ToInt32("Min is greater than Max. Please press go again");
            return message;

        }
        else
        {
            int answer;
            answer = min * max;
            return answer;
        }
    }

    private int Between(int min, int max)
    {
        List<int> BetweenList = new List<int>(max);
        for (int i = min; i < max; i++)
        {
            var swap = randomnum.Next(i - 1);
            BetweenList.Add(BetweenList[swap]);
            BetweenList[swap] = i;

        }
        //return integer
    }
```

Comment: Error in `Convert.ToInt32()` function.I suggest you read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. And its output is an integer, not a string. Besides, if you want a string, just remove `Convert.ToInt32`

Comment: What integer value do you expect `"Min is greater than Max. Please press go again"` to convert to??

Comment: `MinOrMax` is in no way indicative of what the method should do and therefore error diagnosis is difficult.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I know it is stupid but I cant think of another way to try it. How do I go about giving the error message and returning it?

Comment: I don't know if I am overlooking something, but just wanted to point out that Random.Next is overloaded, and one of the overloads lets you specify a min and a max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't convert the string `"Min is greater than Max. Please press go again"` into an `int` value.

As you want the result from the method to be a string in the end, just return a `string` instead of an `int`.

```
private string MinOrMax(int min, int max)
{
    if (min > max)
    {
        string message;
        message = "Min is greater than Max. Please press go again";
        return message;

    }
    else
    {
        int answer;
        answer = min * max;
        return answer.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an error message, you could throw an Exception if your condition doesn't match, something like this. Btw, i won't comment on the logic of the return value.

```
private int MinOrMax(int min, int max)
{
    if (min > max)
    {
        throw new Exception ("Min is greater than Max. Please press go again");
    }
    else
    {
        int answer;
        answer = min * max;
        return answer;
    }
}
```

How to use it

```
private void YourFunction()
{
    // your code
    try
    {
        int getMinOrMax = MinOrMax(yourmin, yourmax);
        // do your stuff
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    // your code
}
```

Ideally, you could write your own Exception but for the sake of this example. I will just use the Exception class